# PDO fetch returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've encountered a little problem.
I have the following code:

```
    $query = $db->prepare('(SELECT last_visit, last_ip FROM user_log WHERE user_id = :id) 
                            UNION
                           (SELECT time AS last_visit, packet_hex AS last_ip FROM crack_log WHERE target_id = :id)
                            ORDER BY last_visit DESC LIMIT 0,10;');
    $query->execute(array(':id'=> $_SESSION['id']));
    $log = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //Last visit/IP

    var_dump($log);
```

Which returns:

```
array(0) { }
```

I've tried the query in phpmyadmin and it worked fine. Can you please help me find the error?

Comment: Did you check `$db->errorInfo()` ?

Comment: any errors? did you session_start(); ?

Comment: Do you have check the query and PDOException on try-catch?

Comment: I don't think you can bind a single parameter multiple times

Comment: @Musa you were right, the multiple :id caused the problem, renaming the second one and adding it solved it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @minitech I meant :id couldn't be used twice, according to Luc M answer that's the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Accorrding to the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

> You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name twice in a
>   prepared statement.
>   You cannot bind multiple values to a single named parameter in, for
>   example, the IN() clause of an SQL statement.

In you case, you should use something like

```
$query = $db->prepare('(SELECT last_visit, 
                               last_ip 
                        FROM user_log 
                        WHERE user_id = :id_1
                       ) 
                        UNION
                       (SELECT time AS last_visit,
                               packet_hex AS last_ip 
                        FROM crack_log 
                        WHERE target_id = :id_2
                       )
                       ORDER BY last_visit DESC LIMIT 0,10;'
                     );
    $query->execute(array(':id_1'=> $_SESSION['id'],
                          ':id_2'=> $_SESSION['id'] 
                         )
                   );
```