# MySQL Union don't return table name correctly

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, union, union-all

i have to search in multiple tables :

```
$query ="(SELECT *, 'product' AS type FROM products WHERE title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR full_description LIKE ? OR keywords LIKE ? OR option1 LIKE ? OR option2 LIKE ? OR option3 LIKE ? OR option4 LIKE ? OR option5 LIKE ? OR option6 LIKE ? OR option7 LIKE ? OR option8 LIKE ?) 
UNION 
(SELECT *, 'article' AS type, NULL AS image1, NULL AS image2, NULL AS image3, NULL AS image4 FROM articles WHERE title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR full_description LIKE ? OR keywords LIKE ? OR option1 LIKE ? OR option2 LIKE ? OR option3 LIKE ? OR option4 LIKE ? OR option5 LIKE ? OR option6 LIKE ? OR option7 LIKE ? OR option8 LIKE ?) 
UNION 
(SELECT *, 'news' AS type, NULL AS image1, NULL AS image2, NULL AS image3, NULL AS image4 FROM news WHERE title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR full_description LIKE ? OR keywords LIKE ? OR option1 LIKE ? OR option2 LIKE ? OR option3 LIKE ? OR option4 LIKE ? OR option5 LIKE ? OR option6 LIKE ? OR option7 LIKE ? OR option8 LIKE ?) 
UNION 
(SELECT *, 'page' AS type, NULL AS categoryID, NULL AS categoryName, NULL AS full_description, NULL AS image, NULL AS image1, NULL AS image2, NULL AS image3, NULL AS image4, NULL AS price FROM pages WHERE title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR option1 LIKE ? OR option2 LIKE ? OR option3 LIKE ? OR option4 LIKE ? OR option5 LIKE ? OR option6 LIKE ? OR option7 LIKE ? OR option8 LIKE ?) 
UNION 
(SELECT *, 'gallery_image' AS type, NULL AS categoryID, NULL AS categoryName, NULL AS full_description, NULL AS image1, NULL AS image2, NULL AS image3, NULL AS image4, NULL AS price FROM gallery_images WHERE title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR option1 LIKE ? OR option2 LIKE ? OR option3 LIKE ? OR option4 LIKE ? OR option5 LIKE ? OR option6 LIKE ? OR option7 LIKE ? OR option8 LIKE ?)";
$selectFromTables = $this->db->prepare($query);
$selectFromTables->execute(array("%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%", "%" . $keyword . "%"));
$found = $selectFromTables->rowCount();
while($rowSearch = $selectFromTables->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $id = $rowSearch['id'];
    $type = $rowSearch['type'];
    $title = $rowSearch['title'];
    echo $id . "->" . $type . "<br />";
}
```

why while loop return this output?

```
23->product
24->product
25->product
27->product
28->product
1->
1->
2->
4->
5->
```

but i expect this output :

```
23->product
24->product
25->product
27->product
28->product
1->article
1->news
2->page
4->page
5->page
```

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192553/pdo-fetch-returns-nothing)

Comment: no it isn't duplicate.

Comment: Read the ANSWER it will solve your problem

Comment: @davidstrachan I can see no named parameter here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that you are [misusing the `UNION` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html).

> The column names from the first SELECT statement are used as the column names for the results returned.

I bet all your tables do not have the same number of columns (please show us the full description of all the tables involved), making your column aliases useless. Likewise, your `title` columns are probably not at the same position in all tables.

Comment: yes my tables do not have the same number of columns and i made them same number by adding NULL columns

Comment: It is too late :) Your `*` means "all columns", so the discrepancy already exists when you add your `NULL` columns -- the aliased `type` columns are not at the same position. Try enumerating your columns explicitely (in the same order for all tables) instead of `*`.

Comment: If you don't need all columns in your application layer, it is always better *not* to pull all data from the database anyways. It often allows faster execution of the query, not to mention a smaller amount of data to return back to the client.

Comment: in this case i need all of them :) thank you for this point :)